# How to not add flow type for particular object

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have an object inside my function

```
let someStyle = {
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
    height: 40,
}
```

and then I am adding properties to it

```
 someStyle.borderRadius: 15
```

here flow is throwing error that **cannot assign 15 to  someStyle.borderRadius beacuse it is missing in object literal**

How can I disable flow for the `someStyle` object? I tried  `// @flow-disable` just above someStyle and it didn't work

Also, if we do `//@flow` is it mandatory to define the type for all objects? inside my stateless function?

Comment: How about to annotate `borderRadius` as optional property of `someStyle` object?

Comment: I think you'll want to use an [unsealed object](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unsealed-objects) since Flow forbids adding properties to sealed objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to solve this:

Option 1: If your style object always has this shape of width, height, backgroundColor, and an optional borderRadius, then you'd probably want to just define the type of the object like so:

```
/* @flow */

type Style = {
    width: number,
    height: number,
    backgroundColor: string,
    borderRadius?: number
}
let someStyle: Style = {
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    height: 40,
}

 someStyle.borderRadius = 15;
```

Option 2: If your style object does not always have this shape, but could be any generic style applied to it, then you will want something more generic.

```
/* @flow */

type Style = {
    [string]: mixed
}
let someStyle: Style = {
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    height: 40,
}

 someStyle.borderRadius = 15;
```

Option 3: If you just want to suppress the error, you can do so like this typically:

```
/* @flow */

let someStyle = {
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    height: 40,
}

// $FlowFixMe
 someStyle.borderRadius = 15;
```